# Deleted metacity folder

Tags: unity, gconf, metacity, application-switcher

I accidently deleted the folder responsible for keybindings, in `gconf-editor` it would be `/apps/metacity/global_keybindings`. I deleted the folder out of my home folder by accident. I'm trying to set some keybindings, but can't because I don't have access to that file anymore. How would I go about getting a default folder for that? I would assume it would be as easy as placing a new folder there.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This should/would be recreated by gconf. Logout and login, and open by gconf-editor.

If this fails, reinstall metacity.